# Unsupported get request - Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a Facebook Pages' feed through the Facebook API.

Putting one of my pages - koodoocreative into my code brings back the data no problem at all.

But when I've tried loading in one of our clients into the API, I get the message...

> Unsupported get request

Attached is an image of the pages' permissions

[image: Facebook Page Permissions]

My PHP code is as follows....

```
// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('','');

$session = new FacebookSession('');

// First Get The Groups' Details...
$request = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        'GET',
        '/'.$app_view->app_view_title
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

$page_name = $graphObject->getProperty('name');

// Next Get The Posts...
$request = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        'GET',
        '/'.$app_view->app_view_title.'/feed?limit=10'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$object = $response->getGraphObject();

$fbdata = $object->getPropertyAsArray('data');

?>
```

Comment: what is "$app_view->app_view_title" exactly, did you debug it?

Comment: Hi @luschn $app_view->app_view_title is a string set for the facebook page i.e koodoocreative

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using username for the pages, e.g. /koodoocreative, whereas the client may not necessarily have this. You should use numerical Page IDs instead, this way, the API call will work for pages with and without vanity URLs.

Comment: Hi @Niraj thanks for the answer, However putting the pages' id in also creates the same error.

Comment: Then the error could mean there is some other restriction on the page, like age or country restrictions. Test the pages with a valid user access_token and see if you get the same error.